# libgdx CameraInputController is way too sensitive, panning kicks in too early

Tags: java, libgdx

Trying to reduce the sensitivity of panning by setting the tap square size, but even setting huge numbers just as in the example below seems to have no effect. On a high-res, small screen phone it is almost impossible to touch something without the panning mode kicking in.

What is the right way to do this? The code below doesn't seem to do anything about it.

```
public class CustomCameraInputController extends CameraInputController {

    public CustomCameraInputController(Camera camera) {
        super(camera);
        this.setTapSquareSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, by debugging LibGdx I found out that the tapSquareSize works differently than I expected. It merely sets a flag but still calls `process()` on finger moves still inside the tap square.

If you want panning/rotation to kick in only when the user leaves the tap square, you need to redefine the `process()` method and transform the camera only when `isPanning()` is true.

Answer (score 0):

for translation also panning, Use `CameraInputController.translateUnits = float value;`,  note there are other two factors that you can use for scrolling and zooming as multiplier,

```
CameraInputController.pinchZoomFactor
CameraInputController.scrollFactor
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using translateUnits already to slow down movement. My problem is rather about differentiating between touch and pan in the same gesture detector, on a small screen phone the slightest mistake results in a pan so it's difficult to pick objects.

Comment: I suggest change setTapSquareSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 5); to something like setTapSquareSize(hypotenuse / 5); this is more accurate, i myself plan to implement panning camera on my project, havn't done anything yet, so I have no idea now, there is a pan method which do nothing on CameraInputController.